# build my project to installer for non python enviroment(both windows and linux)

Tags: python

my directroty sturcture is

```
/src (the source code directory including images)

/src/main.py (main script)

/src/subprojectfile/ (it consist of other several project file include __init__.py)
```

In my project I am using google procolbuffer,pygtk and other common python package like sys,time,thread etc..

I want to build an installer for non python system where user can install my application with out any python support.

Comment: Please accept answers to your questions. You do this by clicking the check mark next to the best one. You should do it for your old questions, too. You've only ever done it on your first question, so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an alternative approach you might check out [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). It doesn't produce a proper installer, but rather standalone executables without external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For windows you can use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and for Linux have a look at [freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze).